# Proof verification: $P(A\cup B)=P(A)\cup P(B)\rightarrow A\subseteq B\vee A\supseteq B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

There are several solutions to the proof $P(A\cup B)=P(A)\cup P(B)\rightarrow A\subseteq B\vee A\supseteq B$ already, however I would like to see if mine is correct:

Proof through contradiction:

Let us assume $A\nsubseteq B\vee A\nsupseteq B$ such that $a\in A\wedge a\notin B, b\in B\wedge b\notin A$.
However, this is impossible as $a,b\in P(A\cup B)=a,b\in P(A)\vee a,b\in P(B)$ and therefore,  $P(A\cup B)=P(A)\cup P(B)\rightarrow A\subseteq B\vee A\supseteq B \blacksquare$

Does this proof work? If not, Why?

Comment: Don't you mean $P(A \cup B)=P(A)+P(B) $? The expression on the left represents a a number, while you are unioning numbers on the right, which does not have a clear definition AFAIK.

Comment: I believe he means $\cup$. $P$ means, at least in my experience, the power *set* (and not just the cardinality thereof).

Comment: I'm more accustomed to seeing $\mathcal{P}$ for power set, and regular $P$ for probability.

Comment: This was asked several dozen times by now. You're asking for a proof verification, so this is not entirely the same. But you can find proofs and compare yours to them all over the place.

Comment: If you are doing a proof by contradiction, you should have an and symbol near the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line is OK.
Then you write $a,b \in P(A \cup B)$ which is *not* true, only $a,b \in A \cup B$ does hold. Try $\{a,b\} \in P(A \cup B)$, which *is* true. 
Then $\{a,b\} \in P(A)$ leads to $\{a,b\} \subseteq A$ which implies $b \in A$, contradiction. (similarly when $\{a,b\} \in P(B)$). You did not specify where the contradiction comes from, but jump straight to the conclusion.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense! So I just forgot to put the two in a group.

Comment: @CluelessButCurious yes, there is a difference between elements and sets of elements which are members of the powers. Type matters.

Comment: @CluelessButCurious: Also note that the negation of $\varphi\lor\psi$ is actually $\lnot\varphi\land\lnot\psi$, and not as you wrote with $\lor$ on the first line.